# HERE SDK: offline maps updates failing

Tags: here-api

I'm working on an android heads up display which has a rather slow bluetooth internet connection.

Every time I trigger performMapDataUpdate it eventually fails with `UNEXPECTED_ERROR`

Prior to the error being returned, I've also had a bunch of logcat exceptions in the background along the lines of:

```
E/NetworkProtocol( 1812): NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
W/System.err( 1812): java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
W/System.err( 1812):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:449)
W/System.err( 1812):    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
W/System.err( 1812):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
W/System.err( 1812):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
W/System.err( 1812):    at com.here.network.NetworkProtocol$GetTask.doInBackground(NetworkProtocol.java:418)
```

Other network tasks seem to work fine, the here maps online caching is working when there are no offline maps, as does the traffic updates etc. Nothing else it likely to be trying to download as much in one go however.

Is there any way to tell the here api to keep retrying on these connections?

Alternatively, is there any way to do an offline maps update from a PC instead?
I'm already using isolated disk cache, and my device does come up as a USB drive when plugged into computer so if I could run the SDK on the desktop and point it to the here cache folder on the USB to update the maps that would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens because MapDataUpdate needs to download comparatively big amount of data.

> Is there any way to tell the here api to keep retrying on these
>   connections?

No, there is no such API (there is a hardcoded number of retries in SDK).

> is there any way to do an offline maps update from a PC instead?

No, that is not possible (you would break MapLoader mechanisms).

BR

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though certainly quite disappointing. I'm not sure what's supposed to break with maploader from external updates because this is basically what we've been doing recently and it's working fine.  I've been running the map updates in a separate android app in an android emulator with the HUD usb drive connected such that the app updates the HUD and it's working well, if a bit tedious having to set up an emulator.